# Help with Google Code Issue Tracker API

Tags: java, android, http, google-code, google-api-java-client

Long story short: I'm trying to post comments and create issues onto Google Code via an Android App called Abugadro.

I followed a very similar piece of code here: 
[Google Spreadsheet API update \ edit with protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254330/google-spreadsheet-api-update-edit-with-protocol)

When trying to post a comment onto the API, I've gotten various errors like 403 and 501 depending on the headers I use.

Anyway, Code talks, so here's my piece:

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/"+projName+"/issues/"+issueId+"/comments/full");

postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type","application/atom+xml;charset=UTF-8");
postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth);
postRequest.addHeader("User-Agent", "abugadro-v"+getResources().getString(R.string.version));
postRequest.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip");
postRequest.addHeader("GData-Version", "1.0");
//postRequest.addHeader("If-Match", "*");//Not entirely sure if I should use this or not

HttpEntity se = new StringEntity(xml,"UTF-8"); //Contains the comment info              
postRequest.setEntity(se);
```

The IssueTrackerAPI is very vague on what sort of headers I should be using to post correctly. 
http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTrackerAPI#Modifying_an_issue_or_creating_issue_comments

P.S. I know there's a gdata-java-client but there's no sane way to use that api on android without dragging ~2mb of jars.

I really appreciate your help, this issue has been driving me insane beyond comprehension. 
Thanks again.

Comment: The latest version of gdata-java-client, even if I drag all of the jars, is no more than 500K. I used the OAuth libraries in it with success. There are a couple of OAuth samples in Android, why don't you give it a shot?

Comment: I did give OAuth a shot, but using the 'desktop application' (As opposed to the Web application) is insanely undocumented. 
Using OAuth, I got stuck at error 400 Bad Request, though I think I might be able to solve those now.

Comment: Oh and the API I was talking about was the ProjectHosting jar, which isn't really meant for Android as it really drags a lot of dependencies. My app is currently ~180kb, adding 500kb of jars sounds like overkill :P

Comment: If the jars are too big to use directly, you can always use them as good example code (if they are open source, which I would guess they are)

Comment: I tried to, I haven't found where they set the correct headers though. All this is is an XML Post to an address. It should be fairly simple and in fact, is probably done by other projects like mylyn.

Answer (score 1):

The best Android library for Google API's is the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), which supports Android. [gdata-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/) doesn't support Android.

google-api-java-client supports the Issue Tracker API, but there is no sample for it yet.  Please [make a request for a sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/entry?template=Request%20a%20Sample).  Meanwhile, you can take a look some of the other examples written for Android like [picasa-atom-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) or [calendar-v2-atom-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default).

Comment: I'll definitely check it out Yaniv, and if I actually get it to work, I'll write the sample myself. Deal? :D